# Modify controller template

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to modify the template used to generate the controller and views when executing?

```
dnx . gen controller -name NameOfController --dataContext DBContextName --model NameOfModel
```

Comment: Have you seen this article?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/23/how-to-customize-scaffolding-templates-for-asp-net-vnext.aspx

Comment: Great, I looked everywhere, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Peter comment I found the templates used and how to use the modified ones.
The location varies a little because of the current version of asp net mvc 6.
Here is the updated location for 1.0.0-beta6

```
c:\Users\[user]\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc\1.0.0-beta6\Templates\
```

and the command to executes changes from that post too:

```
dnx . gen controller -name NameOfController --dataContext DBContextName --model NameOfModel
```

for the rest of the instructions the [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/23/how-to-customize-scaffolding-templates-for-asp-net-vnext.aspx) is still valid.